# Less compiler resolving paths to the wrong directory

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, visual-studio-2013, web-essentials

So here is the environment, VS 2013, WebEssesntials, with HTML Javascript project nothing fancy, just pure html project out of a directory.
I am using less for my CSS, and I am using bootstrap with less as well.
The problem is that all the fonts never get loaded because they point to the wrong directory.

Instead of the path `/content/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot` they end up `/obj/Release/Package/PackageTmp/content/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot`

In the less file variable.less (provided by bootstrap) we have:

```
//** Load fonts from this directory.
@icon-font-path:          "../fonts/";
```

So its a relative path, but it keeps resolving to that non exiting directory, I not sure how to best resolve this and I was wondering if anyone had this problem as well and how they resolved it.

EDIT:

WebEssentials Config File:

```
{
  "BrowserLink": {
    "CssIgnorePatterns": "bootstrap*; reset.css; normalize.css; jquery*; toastr*; foundation*; animate*; inuit*; elements*; ratchet*; hint*; flat-ui*; 960*; skeleton*",
    "EnableMenu": true,
    "EnablePixelPushing": true,
    "ShowMenu": false
  },
  "CodeGen": {
    "AddTypeScriptReferencePath": true,
    "CamelCaseEnumerationValues": false,
    "CamelCasePropertyNames": true,
    "CamelCaseTypeNames": false
  },
  "CoffeeScript": {
    "CompileOnBuild": false,
    "CompileOnSave": true,
    "GenerateSourceMaps": true,
    "LintOnBuild": false,
    "LintOnSave": true,
    "LintResultLocation": "Message",
    "MinifyInPlace": false,
    "OutputDirectory": null,
    "ProcessSourceMapsForEditorEnhancements": true,
    "ShowPreviewPane": true,
    "WrapClosure": true
  },
  "Css": {
    "AdjustRelativePaths": true,
    "AutoMinify": true,
    "Autoprefix": false,
    "AutoprefixerBrowsers": null,
    "GenerateRtlSourceMaps": true,
    "GzipMinifiedFiles": false,
    "MakeMinified": true,
    "OutputDirectory": "/content/",
    "RtlCss": false,
    "RunOnBuild": true,
    "ShowBrowserTooltip": true,
    "ShowInitialInherit": false,
    "ShowUnsupported": true,
    "SyncBase64ImageValues": true,
    "SyncVendorValues": true,
    "ValidateEmbedImages": true,
    "ValidateStarSelector": true,
    "ValidateVendorSpecifics": true,
    "ValidateZeroUnit": true,
    "ValidationLocation": "Messages"
  },
  "General": {
    "AllMessagesToOutputWindow": false,
    "KeepImportantComments": true,
    "ShowWEIgnoreLogs": true,
    "SvgPreviewPane": true
  },
  "Handlebars": {
    "CompileOnBuild": false,
    "CompileOnSave": true,
    "MinifyInPlace": false,
    "OutputDirectory": null
  },
  "Html": {
    "AttributeQuotesRemovalMode": "KeepQuotes",
    "AutoMinify": false,
    "CustomAngularDirectiveList": null,
    "EnableAngularValidation": true,
    "EnableBootstrapValidation": true,
    "EnableEnterFormat": true,
    "EnableFoundationValidation": true,
    "GzipMinifiedFiles": false,
    "ImageDropFormats": [
      {
        "HtmlFormat": "<img src=\"{0}\" alt=\"\" />",
        "Name": "Simple Image Tag"
      },
      {
        "HtmlFormat": "<div><img src=\"{0}\" alt=\"\" /></div>",
        "Name": "Enclosed in Div"
      },
      {
        "HtmlFormat": "<li id=\"item_{1}\"><img src=\"{0}\" alt=\"\" /></li>",
        "Name": "Enclosed as List Item"
      },
      {
        "HtmlFormat": "<div style=\"background-image=url('{0}')\"></div>",
        "Name": "Inline CSS"
      }
    ],
    "MakeMinified": true,
    "MinifyAngularBindingExpressions": false,
    "MinifyKnockoutBindingExpressions": false,
    "OutputDirectory": null,
    "ProcessableScriptTypeList": null,
    "RunOnBuild": false
  },
  "JavaScript": {
    "AutoMinify": true,
    "BlockCommentCompletion": true,
    "EvalTreatment": "MakeImmediateSafe",
    "GenerateSourceMaps": true,
    "GzipMinifiedFiles": false,
    "LintOnBuild": false,
    "LintOnSave": true,
    "LintResultLocation": "Message",
    "MakeMinified": true,
    "OutputDirectory": null,
    "RootDirectory": "/scripts/",
    "RunOnBuild": false,
    "TermSemicolons": true
  },
  "Less": {
    "CompileOnBuild": true,
    "CompileOnSave": true,
    "EnableChainCompilation": true,
    "GenerateSourceMaps": true,
    "MinifyInPlace": false,
    "OutputDirectory": "/content/",
    "ProcessSourceMapsForEditorEnhancements": true,
    "ShowPreviewPane": true,
    "StrictMath": false
  },
  "LiveScript": {
    "CompileOnBuild": false,
    "CompileOnSave": true,
    "GenerateSourceMaps": true,
    "MinifyInPlace": false,
    "OutputDirectory": null,
    "ProcessSourceMapsForEditorEnhancements": true,
    "ShowPreviewPane": true,
    "WrapClosure": true
  },
  "Markdown": {
    "AutoHyperlink": false,
    "AutoNewLines": false,
    "CompileOnBuild": false,
    "CompileOnSave": true,
    "EncodeProblemUrlCharacters": false,
    "GenerateXHTML": true,
    "LinkEmails": false,
    "MinifyInPlace": false,
    "OutputDirectory": null,
    "ShowPreviewPane": true,
    "StrictBoldItalic": false
  },
  "Scss": {
    "CompileOnBuild": false,
    "CompileOnSave": true,
    "EnableChainCompilation": true,
    "GenerateSourceMaps": true,
    "MinifyInPlace": false,
    "NumberPrecision": 5,
    "OutputDirectory": null,
    "OutputStyle": "Expanded",
    "ProcessSourceMapsForEditorEnhancements": true,
    "ShowPreviewPane": true,
    "UseRubyRuntime": false
  },
  "Sprite": {
    "CssOutputDirectory": null,
    "IsVertical": true,
    "LessOutputDirectory": null,
    "Margin": 1,
    "Optimize": true,
    "OutputDirectory": null,
    "RunOnBuild": false,
    "ScssOutputDirectory": null,
    "UseAbsoluteUrl": false,
    "UseFullPathForIdentifierName": true
  },
  "SweetJs": {
    "CompileOnBuild": false,
    "CompileOnSave": true,
    "GenerateSourceMaps": true,
    "MinifyInPlace": false,
    "OutputDirectory": null,
    "ProcessSourceMapsForEditorEnhancements": true,
    "ShowPreviewPane": true
  },
  "TypeScript": {
    "LintOnBuild": false,
    "LintOnSave": true,
    "LintResultLocation": "Message",
    "ShowPreviewPane": true
  }
}
```